# How to append and read text line per line with RichTextBox?

Tags: .net, text, richtextbox, delphi-prism, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a richtextbox on a winform and would like to append and read text line per line.

Take a look at my attempt in my code as follows:

```
method ScriptDlgpas.Execute(memo:RichTextBox): Boolean;
var i:Integer;
begin
  Result := false;

  scriptMemo.Clear;
  var line1 := memo.Lines;
  while (line in line1) do
    scriptMemo.AppendText(line);

  if ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK then
  begin
    memo.Clear;
    var line2 := ScriptMemo.Lines;
    while(line in line2) do
        memo.AppendText(line);
    Result := true;
  end;
end;
```

I have two richtextbox, scriptmemo and memo. I set text to scriptmemo and then I read that back out to append to memo RichTextBox. It all seems logical and of course it compiles successfully, but compiler raises exception, IndexOutofRange, during runtime for the line **var line1 := memo.Lines**

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: There is no var tmplines := memo.Lines in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, either fellow programmers don't know what I am talking about or have no clue how to solve it.

I did figure out my problem and would like to post the answer in the hope it will help others.

Here is the revised and working code:

```
method ScriptDlgpas.Execute(memo:RichTextBox): Boolean;
var i:Integer;
    lines1, lines2 : Array of string;
begin
  Result := false;

  scriptMemo.Clear;
  lines1 := memo.Lines;
  for each aline in lines1 do
  begin
    scriptMemo.AppendText(aline+System.Environment.NewLine);
  end;

  if ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK then
  begin
    memo.Clear;
    lines2 := ScriptMemo.Lines;
    for each aline in lines2 do
    begin
        memo.AppendText(aline+System.Environment.NewLine);
    end;
    Result := true;
  end;
end;
```